# remove duplicate files using fdupes command

Tags: linux

I am using linux. I want to delete duplicate files in a directory recurcively.

I have 100 files ".html" .

i am using fdupes command.

```
      fdupes -r -d dirname
        [1] 9/7.htm                             
        [2] 9/6-7.htm
        [3] 9/6.htm

    Set 1 of 25, preserve files [1 - 3, all]:
```

so if you see the output, i want to retain the filename containing "-" and allow to delete the other duplicate files. because there are hundreds of duplicate files. i cant enter the number to delete each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply do something like this:

```
ls | grep -v '-' | xargs rm
```

removes all files in Folder that does not contain "-"

Comment: sorry i dont want to remove all the files. I only want to remove duplicate files keeping the file name containing "-" (as you see my question 7.htm 6.htm and 6-7.htm are duplicate files. i only want to remove 7.htm and 6.htm not 6-7.htm

Comment: got the clue from your answer. I used `fdupes -R * | grep -v '-' | xargs rm`. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Only firs found duplicate is not deleted in current and below directory

```
fdupes -r -f ./ | xargs rm
```

option `-f` is **very** important, otherwise you delete all of duplicates